# Como enviar html de uma view pra outra view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Possuo uma view (View1.cshtml) com filtros, todo um layout e um gráfico dentro de uma div que é gerado de acordo com os filtros.

Criei uma outra view (View2.cshtml) em branco e gostaria de passar pra ela apenas essa div com o gráfico gerado.

Supondo que tenho esse link no View1:

```
<a href="View2">Enviar HTML</a>
```

E supondo que meu controller está dessa forma:

```
    public ActionResult View1()
    {
        negocio = new View1Negocio();

        View1DTO dto = new View1DTO ();

        dto.LstExercicios = negocio.ObterExercicios();

        return View(dto);
    }

    public ActionResult View2()
    {
        negocio = new View1Negocio();

        View1DTO dto = new View1DTO ();

        dto.LstExercicios = negocio.ObterExercicios();

        return new ViewAsPdf("View2", dto);
    }
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? O que eu teria que fazer nesse código para enviar esse html?

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade pelo que eu entendi, você quer gerar o gráfico e as informações todas dentro de um PDF.

Nunca fiz isso, mas existe um pacote NuGet que acessa um site e o converte em PDF:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pechkin

O site do projeto é:

> https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin

Só que o Pechkin não trabalha com o HTML internamente. O que ele faz é atuar como um um *crawler* que baixa o conteúdo de um endereço e o converte pra PDF.

Se isto resolver, altere o seguinte código na sua View:

```
public FileResult View2()
{
    // configuração global
    GlobalConfig gc = new GlobalConfig();

    // margens, nome do documento, tamanho do papel...
    gc.SetMargins(new Margins(300, 100, 150, 100))
      .SetDocumentTitle("Test document")
      .SetPaperSize(PaperKind.Letter);
    //... etc

    // conversor
    IPechkin pechkin = new SynchronizedPechkin(gc);

    // callbacks
    pechkin.Begin += OnBegin;
    pechkin.Error += OnError;
    pechkin.Warning += OnWarning;
    pechkin.PhaseChanged += OnPhase;
    pechkin.ProgressChanged += OnProgress;
    pechkin.Finished += OnFinished;

    // configuração do objeto
    ObjectConfig oc = new ObjectConfig();

    // codificação, imagens e URL
    oc.SetCreateExternalLinks(false)
      .SetFallbackEncoding(Encoding.ASCII)
      .SetLoadImages(false)
      .SetPageUri("http://enderecodoseusite.com/ControllerDoPDF/View1");
    //... etc

    // gera o PDF
    byte[] pdfBuf = pechkin.Convert(oc);

    return File(pdfBuf, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,
                "SeuArquivo.pdf");
}
```

Acho que você vai precisar gerar um gráfico parametrizando a `Action` pra poder funcionar, não preencher na tela como eu imagino que está sendo feito hoje.

Comment: Obrigado, acho que o PechKin faz o mesmo que o que estou usando: o Rotativa: https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa , talvez o seu seja mais completo. São muitos paramâtros para a geração do meu gráfico, por isso não queria passar na action. Mas  se eu não conseguir passar o html acho que não terei opção.

Comment: Não use o Rotativa. Ele dá problema em determinados ambientes. Já reportei o erro ao desenvolvedor há quase um ano atrás e ele disse que não iria corrigir.

Comment: Bom saber. Vou tentar substituir pelo PechKin então.

Comment: Oi João Paulo, li seu comentário informando que são muitos parâmetros para geração do gráfico. Nesse caso não seria interessante você trabalhar com a View sendo do tipo do seu Model (exemplo GraficoViewModel)? Pergunto isso porque dessa forma, ao dar um post na View1 seus parâmetros seriam todos enviados para uma Action que recebe um parâmetro do tipo GraficoViewModel onde você pode utilizá-los e construir sua View2. Acredito que isso poderia te ajudar ou ser uma alternativa interessante.